Google Sheets, search for number and return specific associated cells
I have two sheets in the same document. One sheet is the master sheet containing account numbers and information, the other is a the daily use of that information. I want each column in the daily sheet to automatically pull certain parts of the information associated with the account, and return it to the daily sheet organized by account number. V or H lookup won't work because the data are strings. Query continues to give a parsing error message. I would also like to pivot the account information, but don't understand the agg error
This is the closest we have gotten, but it still won't actually search for the account number: C2 is the cell in the daily sheet with the account number. For some reason, this returns the labels on columns K through S, but no actual information.
=QUERY(MemberAccountsData!A1:AS181, "select K,L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S where '"&MemberAccountsData!C1:C100&"' matches '"& C2 &"' ")

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.
